# C# Variables to VBScript

Tags: c#, variables, vbscript, arguments, sap-gui

Using this C# application pick a start and ending date range, that SAP will then use to do its query. I have made an application that passes one argument and it worked like that, but it does not work when doing two. Can anyone help?

C#

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String finishDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Process processbefore = new Process();
            processbefore.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe";
            processbefore.Start();
            processbefore.WaitForExit(1000 * 5 * 1);
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Script2.vbs";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = startDate;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = finishDate;
            process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 10);    // wait up to 5 minutes.
        }
    }
}
```

Script2.vbs - VBScript (Abbreviated)

```
startDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
finishDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

I get a subscript out of range for the finishDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

Rest of code after that. I need to know how to add another Argument to pass to the VBScript. I am getting an error if I just add another of the same line.

Comment: Do we really need to see all that code?  I suspect that you can reproduce the problem with six lines of code.  Which line of code in your listing is failing, and what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = startDate;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = finishDate;
```

You want:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = startDate + " " + finishDate;
```

This is because arguments are space separated on Windows, and `process.StartInfo.Arguments` is a single string containing all the arguments.

Note: if one of the arguments has a space in it, you need to place quotes around it or it will be interpreted as multiple arguments. For example:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + startDate + "\" \"" + finishDate "\"";
```